# Run javascript in iframes as well as normal content?

Tags: jquery, iframe, input

I have the following block of code that clears input fields when you click on them:

```
$('.clearinputtext').focus(function(){
    if($(this)[0].defaultValue==$(this).val()) $(this).val('');
});
$('.clearinputtext').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultValue);
});
```

I need that to run inside of iframes as well, is it possible?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the iframe is loaded dynamically with a lightbox, so it's not there when the page loads.

**Solution**

I managed to solve it. Might not be the best solution, but it'll do for now. Since the iframe is loaded with a lightbox when i click a link, it's not there when the page loads, so i needed to run the code for the iframe after it is added. I did that by using the `afterShow` event handler for the lightbox.

Here's the relevant code:

```
afterShow: function() {
    // First get html content of iframe
    var content = $('.fancybox-inner iframe').contents().find('html');
    //Then just apply same code to the iframe
    $(content).find('.clearinputtext').focus(function(){
        if($(this)[0].defaultValue==$(this).val()) $(this).val('');
    });
    $(content).find('.clearinputtext').blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried including the script on the page in the iframe?

Comment: Yes, nothing happened. I don't know why it didn't work, i included the script files correctly but it seems like the script just didn't run. Is that the best way to go around it? If so, i'll try to get it working, but i thought maybe there's a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you included jQuery in the iframe as well? Are there any JS errors?

Comment: Yup, i did indeed include jQuery. No errors. See my edit in OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
innerDoc = iframe[0].contentWindow;

$(innerDoc.document.getElementsByClassName('clearinputtxet')).focus(function(){
if($(this)[0].defaultValue==$(this).val()) $(this).val('');
});

$(innerDoc.document.getElementsByClassName('clearinputtxet')).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this)[0].defaultValue);
});
```

try this out it should work.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but i have a feeling there are better solutions?

Comment: You misspelled innerdoc :) Other than that, i think it should work, except i forgot to mention that the iframe is loaded dynamically with a lightbox. I bet that messes things up a bit?

Comment: Ah :P yea thanks for pointing the innerdoc out. But im not sure if lightbox will mess things up. i havn't used lightbox before.

Comment: The problem is that the iframe isn't there when the page loads, so the script doesn't find any iframes when it runs. At least that's what i guess is happening. I'm getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined` in the console.

Comment: I just found a problem in the code, you'll need to add [0] after iframe.contentWindow so it should be iframe[0].contentWindow. But try to trigger this function after an iframe has loaded.

Comment: Now getting: `TypeError: Object [object HTMLDocument] has no method 'getElementByClassName'`. But just to be sure, your code does the exact same thing as mine, correct? Except that it only applies for iframes? Would it be possible to do something like: `foreach (iframe) { iframe.inheritParentScripts() }` to make the script run inside of the iframes as well?

Comment: Yea this code does the exact thing as your code but for the iframes on that page. Im not sure if inheritParentScripts() is possible. I'm sorry but i don't think i can help anymore than this then:/

Comment: aaahhhhh waiiiit! My fault again!(facepalm) it should be getElementsByClassName not getElementByClassName

Comment: Fair enough, but i don't think that would work still. I need to run the code after the lightbox has opened. I just solved it! See OP for solution. :)